# Not able to backup data from sql server to azure blob container using url

Tags: linux, azure, ssms, azure-blob-storage

My SQL server is hosted on Linux VM. I want to create a database backup on the azure blob container using the URL.

I am trying to run backup query:

```
        use [databaseName]
        backup database [databaseName]
        to url = N'storage account url'
        with credential = 'databasebackup',
        COMPRESSION
```

from the SQL server from windows and I am getting the error

> Msg 3292, Level 16, State 6, Line 3
> A failure occurred while attempting to execute Backup or Restore with a URL device specified. Consult the operating system
> error log for details.
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I have all the necessary permission the azure.
I am tried many thing I am not able to solve my problem.
Please help me out with this.

Comment: Have you appended SAS token with your storage container URL?

Comment: yes sir I appended the sas token with the container url